# How to access values of the static dropdown in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownList("FilterOptions", new List<SelectListItem>()
    { new SelectListItem { Text = "Begins with", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Contains", Value = "2" } ,
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Doesn't contain", Value = "3" } ,
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Ends with", Value = "4" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Doesn't equal", Value = "5" }
    }, "Select filter options", new { @class = "large" })
```

The code given above is for a static dropdown for my search functionality.

How can I access the value of the dropdown in my Controller?

Comment: Is `FilterOptions` a property of your model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : It is the name of the drop down I suppose.

Comment: But are you binding to a model? And what is the signature of the method you posting back to?

Comment: can you mention that you have required `FilterOptions` on submit time or in ajax request?